# Is it possible to start a development server with npm pre hooks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I currently have something like this which runs both my development server and my React app.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "run-p yarn proxy:start react-scripts start",
    "proxy:start": "nodemon test-proxy.js"
},
```

I was hoping to to do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "predev": "nodemon test-proxy.js",
    "dev": "react-scripts start"
},
```

But due to `nodemon` never exiting it keeps watching files until you exit the process yourself, the `dev` script never gets fired.

Is it possible to run `predev`, let it run in the background (keep running `nodemon` to watch file changes and preferably keep logging any I/O events) and also run my React start script?

Comment: Perhaps try utilizing [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). However, you'll probably have to avoid using a `pre` hook  and do something like `"dev": "concurrently \"nodemon test-proxy.js\" \"react-scripts start\""`as there seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently/issues/120) with handling `pre`/`post` hooks.

Comment: I am already using `npm-run-all` to do that. Was hoping to make it more clear by changing it to a pre hook but sounds like it might not be possible.